# What's the name of this type of lock?

Tags: doors, lock

I need to replace this bathroom lock:

[image: bathroom lock]

I drew the blue and red lines to show that the bolt and the handle are "staggered". Most locks I find have both in the same line, which is a problem for me because then the bolt does not align with the hole in the door frame.

What is the name of this type of lock where these two lines don't match up?

As a side note (in case this is important) the case depth must be 76mm.

Comment: It is a mortise lock as found on this question a couple weeks ago(only reason I know).  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/281939/how-to-change-locks-on-front-door-with-old-handle-set

Comment: Mortise lock in bathroom configuration (I'm guessing thumb turn on inside,  not sure what they'd put outside.)  There isn't a specific name for this variant that I know of, but I'd try taking it to a locksmith and see if they can find it in a catalog. A locksmith in your area is likely to have seen most of the locally used variants.

If you can't match it exactly, drilling another hole for the new shaft location isn't a bad solution. One of the reasons for escutcheon plates is that they hide mistakes and changes.

Comment: (Nominated to reopen because the question is about terminology for a relevant detail.)

Comment: Getting something perfectly matching is good, but moving or installing a new strike plate is not rocket science. And I don't know where you are in the world, but my local Home Depots stock mortise locks that aren't total junk.